# Update first n records in SQLite

Tags: android, sqlite

I want to update first n records in my SQLite DB from android app. Following are the queries that I've tried so far. I'm getting syntax error near `order`.

```
update label set label_is_used = 1 where label_name !='temp' and label_cnt != 0 order by label_cnt desc limit 3
------------------------------------
update label set label_is_used = 1 where label_name !='temp' and label_cnt != 0 order by label_cnt limit 3
```

From the [docs](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_update.html), this should work as it fits in the syntax.
[image: syntax]

Where I'm getting wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [documentation you linked to](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_update.html) says:

> If SQLite is built with the SQLITE_ENABLE_UPDATE_DELETE_LIMIT compile-time option then the syntax of the UPDATE statement is extended with optional ORDER BY and LIMIT clauses

That option is not enabled by default, and certainly not on Android.

As a workaround, determine the records to be updated in a subquery:

```
UPDATE label
SET label_is_used = 1
WHERE label_id IN (SELECT label_id   -- or whatever you use as ID
                   FROM label
                   WHERE label_name != 'temp'
                     AND label_cnt != 0
                   ORDER BY label_cnt DESC
                   LIMIT 3);
```

Comment: This should work. But, any idea about how to enable that option and make my query work? Curious. :)

Comment: Oh, just recompile and reinstall that part of the Android OS.